# Some parts of my external CSS file are not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use an external CSS file to style my web page, here's a snippet:

```
body {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    color:yellow;
    font-size:125%;
    border: 3px yellow;
}
.menu {
    height: 800px;
    float:right;
}
...
```

Here is how I call the CSS file in my head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
```

The weird thing is that everything else in my style.css works fine and displays as I want. It's just the body tag that doesn't show correctly. I am really lost.
There is no other HTML files, nor other CSS files. I encountered this problem really early on in my process which is all the more confusing.

Comment: Can you add some context? Is this a website you put together with just html and css? Are there any additional style sheets?

Comment: I just started out, there only is this html file and this CSS file.

Comment: you can try clearing cache, in case your browser is still retaining some old copy of the css

Comment: Thank you ! Clearing the cache did the trick :)

Comment: Your border attribute needs a descriptor, solid, dashed, or dotted.